# How to map YAML configuration to POJOs with objects of classes

Tags: java, yaml, lombok, snakeyaml

I have the following YAML config

```
lookupKeys:
  - aggregate_location_city:
    outputKey: city_id
    - file1:
        source: ./pincode_to_city_mapping.csv
        primaryColumn: 0
        secondaryColumn: 1
    - file2:
        source: ./new_geo_city.csv
        primaryColumn: 1
        secondaryColumn: 0
```

The corresponding configuration class is

```java
@Getter
@Setter
public class Configuration {
    private ArrayList<LookupKey> lookupKeys;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    public class LookupKey{
        private String outputKey;
        private ArrayList<MappingFile> mappingFiles;

        @Getter
        @Setter
        public class MappingFile{
            private String source;
            private int primaryColumn;
            private int secondaryColumn;
        }
    }
}
```

How do I get the config file mapped to the Configuration class? I am using snake-yaml for this. A simple `yaml.loadAs(in, Configuration.class)` is not working.

Answer (score -2):

Do not use inner classes. LookupKey must not be defined inside Configuration.

Comment: While it's valid to do so, simply telling "Do's & Don'ts" in this context is not really going to teach anyone anything. In the same manner that code-only answers are valid but unrecommended in most contexts. Please explain *why* one should *"not use inner classes"*, and *why* one's *"`LookupKey` must not be defined inside `Configuration`"*.

Comment: Inner classes require reference to the outer class. SnakeYAML will not be able create it. Just use top level classes. I should have mentioned it in the documentation for SnakeYAML.

Comment: So, `LookupKey` can be declared `static class`, this solves it?

Comment: Yes, but than it is no more inner class

Answer (score -2):

To avoid having to maually code - test - correct your own Mapping classes forever,
you can have Java files generated for you in two steps:

- [Yaml to JSON online conversion](http://codebeautify.org/yaml-to-json-xml-csv)
- [JSON to POJO online conversion](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org)

This gives you Java classes that can be used together with Jackson.

Comment: This doesn't teach us anything about the usage of snake-yaml in this context, nor is it particularly good practice to do two model-transformations when deserializing data (especially considering that you'd want to use streaming processing in most cases).